# simple_form: specify id of text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I've got the simple simple_form below. I'm trying to make the ID of the input field be 'my-id', but the solution below doesn't work (the id is 'comment_body'). How can I specify the id for that input field?

```
= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f|
    = f.input :body, as: :string, html: {id: "my-id"}
    = f.button :submit
```

I've also tried

```
    = f.input :body, as: :string, id: "my-id"
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:input_html` works, not `:html`.

```
 = f.input :body, as: :string, input_html: {id: "my-id"}
```

Comment: Thank You @bevanb !!!  I spent hours on this and finally inspected my HTML form and realized it wasn't assigning the ID I told it to use.  I had it as: 

```f.input :logo, as: :file, id: 'logoFile'```
 
It was assigning the id as **company_logo** I have NO IDEA where that ID came from but it wasn't until I changed it to: 

```f.input :logo, as: :file, input_html: {id: 'logoFile'}```

that it TOOK my ID of **'logoFile'** instead of it making up its own out of the clear blue sky.
I am not sure where 'company_logo' came from?!?   

This is on Rails v6.1.5 (6/15/2022)

Answer (score 1):

The way to add an ID to a simpleform input field has changed since this question was first answered.

The latest syntax (version 3.2.0) would be what the op tried:

```
 = f.input :body, as: :string, id: "my-id"
```

I thought I'd add an update to this question as it comes near to the top of Google when searching for 'simpleform id'.